# Running an Android project on real device doesn't include any changes

Tags: android, android-studio

I am running my Android project on a real device. So if I make a change and run it again, I get the old version of the app without the new changes. I have to uninstall the app and run it every time to get the new changes. Can I somehow run it with all of the new code changes like on the emulator?

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Canary 3
Build #AI-211.7442.40.2111.7518594, built on July 2, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.11.0-44-generic
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 3072M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.instant.shutdown=false, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.intellij.plugins.vscodekeymap (211.4961.30), org.toml.lang (0.2.155.4114-211), com.thoughtworks.gauge (211.6693.111), org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.ide (1.0.0-alpha4-build310), com.suusan2go.kotlin-fill-class (1.0.7), org.intellij.plugins.markdown (211.7142.37)
Current Desktop: ubuntu:GNOME
```

And my deps

```
ext.versions = [
        minSdk               : 24,
        compileSdk           : 31,
        versionCode          : 1,
        versionName          : '0.0.1',

        gradleBuildTool      : '7.0.2',
        spotlessGradle       : '5.15.0',
        kotlin               : '1.6.0',

        // material
        materialVersion      : '1.3.0-alpha03',

        // compose
        composeVersion       : '1.1.0-rc01',
        constraintVersion    : '1.0.0-rc01',
        activityVersion      : '1.4.0',
        composeNavVersion    : '2.4.0-rc01',

        // compose image loading
        landscapistVersion   : '1.4.3',

        // compose compatibles
        orchestraVersion     : '1.1.1',

        // compose insets
        accompanistVersion   : '0.20.2',

        // architecture components
        fragmentVersion      : '1.3.1',
        lifecycleVersion     : '2.4.0',
        roomVersion          : '2.3.0',
        archCompomentVersion : '2.1.0',
]
```

Comment: Android Studio contains multiple techniques to apply code changes even to running applications, may be those techniques are compatible with your app (or the device)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try hitting the "Apply Code Changes"?

[image: Apply Code Changes]